# Sorting files drawn from a folder by name for a graph

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, graph, plot

I have a code to count strings from each file (each file is a month in a year, i.e 2012 04, 2006 11, etc.) in a folder and sum them:

```
mypath = "C:\Users\Desktop\FILE\\"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f))]
result = {}
for f in onlyfiles: #imports all files in CSV folder as 'onlyfiles'
    with open(mypath + f, 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
        a1 = content.count('Bacon')
        a2 = content.count('Eggs')
        total = a1 + a2
    result[f.strip(".csv")] = total
```

It then puts the values in a dictionary:

```
new_dictionary = {}
count = 0
for m, n in result.items():
    print 'The number of bacon and eggs in', m, "was", n
    count += 1
    new_dictionary['month_{}'.format(count)] = result
```

and finally plots them on a graph:

```
plt.plot(result.values())
plt.ylabel('Bacon and eggs seen in this month')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.title('Amount of times bacon and eggs seen over time')
plt.xticks(range(len(result)), result.keys())
plt.show()
```

However when it prints the graph the time (months etc) is in a random order rather than the order of them over time as they are in the folder like such:

[image: Graph]

How can i get the graph to plot them in a logical order?

I have tried using list.sorted methods but it just ends up printing strange things.

NB: Data is made up as real data is sensitive, but principle the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While filling `new_dictionary` you should supply the values in order:

```
for m, n in sorted(result.items()):
```

Comment: Still prints the graph in a random order :/

Comment: However it does now `print m, n` in order now! Just not the graph!

Comment: Applying the sorted function to the xticks keys fixed it so i'm giving you the right answer as it helped me on the way to python victory

Comment: High Five! I'm glad you finally found a solution by sticking to it. And thanks anyway, I'm just starting.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html as this may be beneficial to you.

You can utilize "os.path.split()" to split the file path so you have a list of:

```
['root path','file.csv']
```

Then you can use os.path.splitext() to return another list of:

```
['file','csv']
```

If you had: 2015-03.csv, you could do:

```
filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(f)[1])[0] 
# get list item 1 from os.path.split() and use that 
# in os.path.splitext() and grab the first list item
```

Then you can add it to your dictionary or use nested dictionaries like:

```
mypath = "C:\Users\Desktop\FILE\\"
result = {}
for f in [f for f in os.path.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(f)]:
    with open(os.path.abspath(f), "r") as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
        a1 = content.count('Bacon')
        a2 = content.count('Eggs')
        total = a1 + a2
    result[os.path.splitext(os.path.split(f)[1])[0]] = {"Bacon":a1,"Eggs":a2,"Total":total}

for filename in sorted(result.iterkeys()):
    print("File: {0}; Bacon: {1}; Eggs: {2}; Total: {3}").format(filename,result[filename]["Bacon"],result[filename]["Eggs"],result[filename]["Total"])
```

Have you considered regular expressions? re.findall() returns a list of results:

```
bacon = re.findall(re.compile(r"bacon",re.MULTILINE),content)
eggs = re.findall(re.compile(r"eggs",re.MULTILINE),content)

print(str("Total bacon: {0}").format(len(bacon)))
print(str("Total eggs: {0}").format(len(eggs)))
```

If you're working with a large file then you may want to consider mmap to read the entire contents into memory. Please take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html for more information.

Comment: This is a great response but I'm quite happy with the majority of the code as is atm! The lit of strings to find is also 50+ so I don't want to rewrite it all :) It picks out strings I say then sums them etc. I am however working with 20GB+ of data so I will consider looking at mmap!

Comment: 50+ lines isn't bad, I've used TextWrangler or Notepad++ to change the structure of several lines of code in the past. I'm used to working with datasets larger than that with my custom performance monitoring tools for the OneFS distributed filesystem but I store my data in SQLite databases. Structured data may be a bit of a pain to implement and will cost a few CPU cycles in the short-term but it will save you CPU cycles and a receding hairline in the long-term.